# How to select subset of rows grouped by the code and transpose them to one row with the code as the key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

Having an ingredients table with location-dependent description of the materials like:

```
code | location | description
-----|----------|------------
0    | loc1     | descr 01
0    | loc2     | descr 02
0    | loc3     | descr 03
     |          |
1    | loc1     | descr 11
1    | loc2     | descr 12
1    | loc3     | descr 13
     |          |
8    | loc1     | descr 81
8    | loc2     | descr 82
8    | loc3     | descr 83
```

I need to display one ingredient (with the same value in the `code` column) on one line with columns named by locations. Better to say, I need an SQL query to transform the above rows into the rows below:

```
code | cLoc1    | cLoc2    | cLoc3    
-----|----------|----------|-----------    
0    | descr 01 | descr 02 | descr 03
1    | descr 11 | descr 12 | descr 13
8    | descr 81 | descr 82 | descr 83
```

How can it be done if the `loc1 loc2 loc3` or the like type of argument is passed, to produce just the columns for the location even though there can be more locations in the upper table? Also, if the description for certain location is missing in the upper table that cell should be empty string or NULL in the lower table.

(I guess that the tailored SQL query must be generated into a string variable and that one should be executed. But how should the code look like?)

Comment: HINT: `PIVOT` is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `case when` with *Aggregate function*

`MAX` function and `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT code,
      MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'loc1' THEN description END ) cLoc1, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'loc2' THEN description END ) cLoc2,   
      MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'loc3' THEN description END ) cLoc3        
FROM T
GROUP BY code
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/902c6f/1)

If your data contain `'`, you can use `''` to escape apostrophe in condition.

```
SELECT code,
      MAX(CASE WHEN location = '''loc1''' THEN description END ) cLoc1, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN location = '''loc2''' THEN description END ) cLoc2,   
      MAX(CASE WHEN location = '''loc3''' THEN description END ) cLoc3        
FROM T
GROUP BY code
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c5135/1)

---

If you want to dynamic create columns, you need to write a dynamic pivot script.

This is a sample.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(CASE WHEN location = ''''' + location +''''' THEN description END ) AS ' + location
            FROM T
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT code, ' + @cols + ' FROM T GROUP BY code'

execute(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2c5d151c57f4a1d9ef791dadc79811d)

**[Results]**:

```
| code |    cLoc1 |    cLoc2 |    cLoc3 |
|------|----------|----------|----------|
|    0 | descr 01 | descr 02 | descr 03 |
|    1 | descr 11 | descr 12 | descr 13 |
|    8 | descr 81 | descr 82 | descr 83 |
```

Comment: Thanks D-Shih. I have used apostrophes only to express the values are strings. I will remove them from the question. I like the solution, and I will try it tomorrow.